# finding month given week number of the year in R

Tags: r

I have week_of_the_year column (0-52) in my data. I want to find out which month or (some cases 2 months) that it belongs to. I finally need a data frame like

```
week_of_year, jan, feb,.....dec
     5          1    1  0 0  0
```

if fifth week belongs to both jan and feb those columns to be filled with 1 and others with 0s. I finally want to merge the above dataframe with my own dataframe.
Help me with this please.

Comment: Do you know what year? Do you know if they're [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)? Do they start on Sunday? Monday? Jan 1? 0 or 1 based? Leap weeks? There are `week` and `isoweek` functions in lubridate and data.table, but without more information the best you can do is a rough estimate, e.g. `setNames(0:52, months(as.POSIXlt(as.Date('2017-01-01') + 0:52 * 7)))`

Comment: Yes I have Years information. I created a sequence dataframe of dates and extracted month,week from that, then did dcast and finally merged with my data and it worked fine. Thanks